# Can I filter out all rows corresponding to reference list in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list of IDs that I would like to select in a excel sheet. I am used to using the filter function to search for 1 ID, but now I would like to filter out all the rows with that match the ID in another columns of another sheet.

So for example, I have this reference list and other column to filter on:

```
REF:    column to filter sheet on:    output sheet desired has only these rows:
 a             a                            a  
 c             b                            c
 d             c                            d
 z             d                            z
 x             ...                          x
 y             z                            y
```

I am using the latest version of excel but I'm not used to using visual basic. However, any solution to this problem is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope can be achieved by 'VLOOKUP' function. Please try the below steps and check your outcome.

Select a cell which is next to the column of REF. See the screenshot.

Go to Formulas > Insert Function > refer the screenshot and click on the “Lookup_Value” and choose the first column (“Sheet 1 column A”) > click on the “Table Array” and choose the column other sheet >Click on the “Col_index_num” and enter number ‘1’ > Click on the “Range_Lookup” and enter number ‘0’

[image]

Now you will have a value ‘#N/A’ in the selected cell which you have selected. Now copy ‘#N/A’ and paste it in the same column till the end of all the row in the first sheet. Insert the Filter option for all columns. Filter out all ‘#N/A’ and enter No in the next cells. Vice versa, filter out all values except ‘#N/A’ and enter Yes in the next cells. See the screenshot.

[image]

Now, filter out all Yes field to check the same ID's in both the columns.

Hope this helps.